# Is it possible to set the ObjectContext.CommandTimeout in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, .net, silverlight, entity-framework

I am working on a Silverlight project that uses Entity Framework. The service time-outs when the query takes a few seconds and should return something like 3MB+ of data.

I have found that I can put something like this.ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = NNN in the constructor of the domanincontext, but I wonder if it is possible to put this in the web.config instead?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to set something in config and have it picked up automatically. What you can do is to add a custom property to the config and read it and set `ObjectContext.CommandTimeout` to the value you read. Trying to figure out why you get the timeout and trying fixing this would be even better. I think the default timeout is 30 secs so your queries probably take more that that. Maybe you don't need all the data (if it is for humans 3MB+ seems a lot of data to consume and understand)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are correct on your assumptions that this is not a time-out problem. We found that the problem was the size limit of the serializer. There were too many rows/objects returned for the serializer. Increasing the size limit in the web.config fixed the issue.